# Play scala browse the image then crop and submit into form

Tags: javascript, jquery, scala, playframework, playframework-2.0

In My Play Framework Scala project I would like to upload images on form submission,for this purpose I have used the below code

**form.scala.html**

```
    @form(routes.Users.register(),'enctype -> "multipart/form-data") {
 @inputFile(field = algorithmForm("profileimage"), '_label -> "User Icon")
       <input type="submit" value="Add user" >
}
```

**Users.scala**

```
 request.body.file("profileimage").map { picture =>
        import java.io.File
        val filename = picture.filename
        val contentType = picture.contentType

        picture.ref.moveTo(new File("D:\\User\\"+filename))   
        Ok("file created")
      }.getOrElse {
        Redirect(routes.Application.index).flashing(
          "error" -> "Missing file")
      }
```

**What I actually need**

need to show the selected image in `view` page then do a `cropping` operation in that image,on form `submit` need to upload that cropped image into the specified location.So I have used https://github.com/andyvr/picEdit this plugin I have done all those thinks using this `plugin` but unfortunately I couldn't submit the form it was not working.So please suggest any `plugin` with this mentioned functionality along with submit option enable.

**Edit**

I have `cropped` and `submitted` the `image` with other `form` values.It is copying a file in a particular mentioned directory,but the image is `original` one not a `cropped` image.actually I need a cropped image to save in that corresponding directory. and also it doesn't redirect to other pages.I used `Ok("submitted")` ,`Redirect()` methods but it doesn't do that.

Comment: This question will probably be closed, as you are asking for off-site resources. Try to improve your question: What exactly is not working? Is there any error?

Comment: I used https://github.com/andyvr/picEdit plugin in my project for crop the sleeted image before submit. but  the form submission is not working because of integrating that plugin.if I don't add that plugin the form submission is working

Answer (score 2):

Have you checked **Picture Cut** JQuery plugin [Github URL](https://github.com/TuyoshiVinicius/jQuery-Picture-Cut).
I hope it will be helpful. This plugin has the crop, drag-drop and other features. Please take a look at it.

Otherwise you can check following [link](http://www.jqueryrain.com/demo/jquery-crop-image-plugin/) which showcase few more such plugins

Comment: I will check and let you know